# How to link DOM Element to setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm having a bit of fun with a dynamic background for my website. Now I'm trying to lock the rotating tiles with a mouse-click, but since I revert the tiles to their original position with `setTimeout` I want to cancel that as well for each individual tile.

```
// Rotate tiles.
$(".tile").on('mouseover', function () {
    var tile = $(this);
    tile.toggleClass('rotate');

    setTimeout(function () {
        tile.removeClass('rotate');
    }, 4000);
});

// Lock the tiles.
$(".tile").on('click', function () {
    $(this).off('mouseover');
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
    // clear timeout?
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Ef3LP/3/)**

The only viable option I've come up with so far is to assign the tiles a new class with identical css properties to overrule the result of the time-out, which is obviously unlikable. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the timeout in data:

```
tile.data("timer",setTimeout(function() {
    tile.removeClass('rotate');
});
```

Then you can clear the timeout later:

```
clearTimeout(tile.data("timer"));
```

Disclaimer: I'm not a jQuery user. Personally I'd attach the property to the DOM element itself, but I'm fairly sure `.data()` is how you pass data around in jQuery.

Comment: +1 for storing it on the element. Using `.data` is terribly expensive in comparison. Even if jQuery is used, this is how it should be done IMO.

Comment: @cookiemonster Heh... Using jQuery is terribly expensive in comparison to... [not using jQuery](http://vanilla-js.com/). That link will never get old...

Comment: I'm trying `this.timerId = setTimeout(..` `clearTimeout(this.timerId);` but it's not working as expected? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Ef3LP/4/)

Comment: Hmm, that's... oh, make sure you `clearTimeout(this.timerId)` befoer you start a new timer, otherwise the old one will be "lost" and can't be cancelled.

Comment: Gonna need a fiddle of what you're trying with my code.

Comment: I've tried every variation I could think of. Log says it's clearing the same ID as it has last set, but it has no effect. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Ef3LP/5/)**